# Unable to use min-lines option in grunt-jscpd

Tags: gruntjs

Unable to use min-lines option in grunt-jscpd

```
grunt.initConfig({
  jscpd: {
    javascript: {
          options: {
              min-lines: 3
              },
          path: 'lib/js/'
    }
  }
}
```

If I use as mentioned in above code, Grunt gives the error.

In documentation

```
https://github.com/mazerte/grunt-jscpd#min-lines
```

The author just mentioned `min-line` option but haven't shared the format, how to use it in code.

So does anyone knows what is the proper syntax for using min-line attribute

My main intention is to check duplicate code for minimum line= 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `min-lines` property in single or double quotes (`"min-lines"`) to avoid the grunt error. The same applies for `min-tokens` if being used. E.g.

```js
grunt.initConfig({
    jscpd: {
        javascript: {
            options: {
                'min-lines': 8, // <-- Include single/double quotes.
                'min-tokens': 30 // <-- also for min-tokens if used.
            },
            path: 'lib/js/'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For folks that came here with a similar problem: If you are passing the config as `.json` via the `jscpd -c path_to_json.json` option:

Note that instead of `"min-lines"` you have to use `"minLines"`.